# В чем разница условия?

Tags: java

Несколько раз натыкался на такую штуку, когда определяют условие пишут так

`if (null == instance)` 
хотя традиционно всегда пишут наоборот 
`if (instance == null)`
какая разница? или кому как нравиться?

Answer (score 9):

Во втором случае можно ошибиться и написать `if (instance = null)`, то есть выполнить присваивание, а не проверку. Это скорее всего, пошло из C/C++.
В Java компилятор выдаст ошибку (однако, если `instance` имеет тип `Boolean`, то запись `if (instance = null)` приведет к `NullPointerException`).

Comment: За что минус-то?)

Comment: блин серьезно не туда нажал... А как поменять?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko еще раз нажать на минус

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не подумайте, что давлю, но если вы поставили минус случайно - уберите, пожалуйста. Это вполне хороший и полный ответ

Comment: Нет проблем, на самом деле случайно. Но когда я нажимаю появляется сообщение "Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор пока ответ не будет отредактирован"

Comment: Не суть, просто подумал, что кто-то увидел ошибку в ответе, но решил не говорить об этом.

Answer (score 4):

Мастера Йоды нотация называется это. Слева константу ставят, ошибки замены сравнения на присваивание избегая (ошибку времени трансляции или компиляции вызывает это).

Однако в языках, в которых условие в `if ()` должно иметь специальный тип `boolean` (в том числе Java) это лишнее, поскольку такой код не скомпилируется в любом случае.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то в случае if (instance = null) можно получить NullPointerException? А в обратном, мы сравниваем с константой и исключаем такой вариант?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko На самом деле в Java это не поможет, поскольку в любом случае при присваивании в условии `if ()` не получится `boolean` и ошибка "выпадет" на стадии компиляции.

Comment: @tutankhamun да ладно?! http://goo.gl/0PMaem

Comment: Значит это просто привычка с других языков и в java нет разницы как писать условие справа налево или слева на право?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko разницы нет, иначе какой смысл проверять объект на ```null``` если сама проверка будет выкидывать NPE?

Comment: @Vartlok Компилируется только если `instance` является объектом `Boolean`, тут вы правы. Не додумал эту ситуацию

Comment: Интересно, а как будет проходить проверка если `Boolean` допустим `if(true = null)` или  `if(false = null)` что тогда?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `unexpected type`

Comment: В смысле так нельзя? Но компиляцию пройдет, верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko неа, литерал же не `lvalue` и слева от знака присваивания стоять не может.

Comment: тогда что показывает своим примером Vartlok несколько комментариев выше. Там ссылка на пример

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko что если `instance` имеет тип `Boolean` (именно объект, то есть с большой буквы), то `if (instance = null)` скомпилируется, и выдаст исключение уже во время выполнения, что не есть хорошо