# Зачем null слева от равно а не справа

Tags: c#

Иногда вижу вот такую конструкцию странную и не знаю зачем так делают

```
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;  
    if (null != principal)  
    {  
       foreach (Claim claim in principal.Claims)  
       {  
          Response.Write("CLAIM TYPE: " + claim.Type + "; CLAIM VALUE: " + claim.Value + "</br>");  
       }  
    }
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8

Может глупый вопрос но не понимаю в чем прикол что null слева, почему нельзя записать так

```
    if (principal != null)
```

Что это дает и где можно про это почитать

Comment: нотация йоды это называется. обычно это ставится при `==`, чтоб не допустить банальное присваивание

Comment: Имху [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490352/213987), даже несмотря на то, что языки разные - но делать же для каждого языка?

Comment: @AK на каждый язык точно не стоит. Хоть и есть отличия для Java и C#, в C# с присваиванием вообще не скомпилируется, в Java  может при определенных условиях, но все равно голосую за дубль.

Comment: Хм. Не знал, что это называется нотация йоды, в c# использую, если с null сравнивается достаточно длинное выражение.